# The JavaScript event "onchange" of input file doe'snt work in Samsung Galaxy S3 - Android 4.1.2

Tags: javascript, android, onchange, galaxy, file-io

The problam only in Samsung Galaxy S3 and Android 4.1.2
The Code is:

```
<input type="file" id="filUpload" runat="server" accept="image/*" onchange="uploadImage()">
```

I clicking the input, choosing an image from the galary...
but the event "uploadImage" doe's not running.

But!! (Attention):
Afer I refersh the page a few times - it's working well!

Tahnk's!!